# Moving data between drives CentOS 6 + cPanel

Tags: linux, centos, mysql5.5

Recently, my server crashed. The hosting company has installed new CentOS on a replacement drive and attached the old drive to my server. I have installed and setup cPanel onto the new server and created similar user accounts etc like my old server.

Transferring public_html would be easy as it would involve copy-paste of data. I want to know how I should proceed to move data from my old SQL installation into the new server.

Any help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because control panel topic are off topic. Also, none of us can give you an answer to whether or not your database should be restored. You know the application, we don't.

Comment: I wasn't asking help on the control panel per say. I was just giving out information as to what I have installed.

I just wanted help in moving the data which Bahrain Admin has done :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move MySQL DB to another server](http://serverfault.com/questions/367596/move-mysql-db-to-another-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im assuming that the database server is mysql and that the previous OS was centos and you only want to move the DB to the new disk

I found this answer on one of the StackExchange forums. Have you tried this method?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another

Old Server

```
Stop mysql server
Copy contents of datadir to another location on disk (~/mysqldata/*)
Start mysql server again (downtime was 10-15 minutes)
compress the data (tar -czvf mysqldata.tar.gz ~/mysqldata)
copy the compressed file to new server
```

New Server

```
install mysql (don't start)
unzip compressed file (tar -xzvf mysqldata.tar.gz)
move contents of mysqldata to the datadir
Make sure your innodb_log_file_size is same on new server, or if it's not, don't copy the old log files (mysql will generate these)
Start mysql
```